# When building a project, cannot find a sub project on the server

Tags: javascript, c#, build, dependencies, sln-file

I am trying to build the project on the server, and it says it cannot find a test project (sub project). I have recently added this sub project to the project. I checked the folder and it shows me the abc.js.csproj file. I run 'git clean -xfd' and then build the project and it builds successfully. But when I try to run the same on server, it fails with error cannot find the abc.js.csproj.

I looked for dependencies and they looks okay to me. My guess is during merge the sln file might have got into bad state, but not sure how I can revert to a good file , and preserve my newly added subprojects at the same time.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is quite vague and have very little information. Based on the information available, I am providing below mentioned possibilities to fix the problem.

There could be multiple reasons why the build server is not able to find the project. First of all you need to see why build server is not able to find the project. As mentioned by you, seems you have added external project to the solution. Check if any of the below mentioned trick helps:

- If you have added external project, then check if the source of that project is getting downloaded on the build server.
- If you have added external project, which is outside of your solution folder then you need to add project with relative path.
- Check if that project is checked in to the source control.
- Check if you have added all of the dependent assembly/project references.

Comment: I had missed one of the dependencies for the project, so it wasn't compiling at all